# I am unable to upgrade my PHP version in my docker wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to move my existing multisite network to the Docker/Kubernetes setup for easy backup and management.
I have an environment setup at

MYSQL : 5.7.2

PHPMYADMIN: Latest

WordPress: 5.6 (the PHP version in this installation is 7.3 which I need to update)
I want to upgrade to PHP 8.0.0

I was suggested to use a docker file which I did,
-->  https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest/php8.0/apache/Dockerfile
When running this with a correction in line 149 :

```
    RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I get the following error,

> ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
> PS C:\Users\dev> docker-compose up -d
> dev_db_1 is up-to-date
> Starting dev_wordpress_1 ...
> Starting dev_wordpress_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for dev_wordpress_1  Cannot start service wordpress: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I need your help in getting my WordPress image running, I am unsure about what does this, `(docker-entrypoint.sh)` contain, or where to place it.

Your help and guidance is well appreciated in advance.

Regards,
Aaditya

Comment: *I am unsure about what does this, (docker-entrypoint.sh) contain, or where to place it*. its this file https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest/php8.0/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the script `docker-entrypoint.sh` at https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/5bbbfa8909232af10ea3fea8b80302a6041a2d04/latest/php8.0/apache, the same folder where you get the Dockerfile.

`docker-entrypoint.sh` is the script that is executed once the Docker image is loaded (so as the name says it's the image entry-point).

I'm able to build and load the Wordpress image with PHP 8.0 and Apache with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress.git
cd wordpress/latest/php8.0/apache
podman build -t wordpress_php8 .
podman run --rm -it -p 8000:80 localhost/wordpress_php8:latest
```

Now I'm able to connect to the site http://127.0.0.1:8000/

[image]

No need of any correction.

Note that you can use `docker` instead of `podman`, if you prefer.

Works also with this simple `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: "./"
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
```

`sudo docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should not try to update php inside a docker container.
Instead find out how the container is built, then build one that contains the php version you desire. This will keep the image simple and small.